# What does "field" in field oxide mean?

Tags: circuit-design, integrated-circuit, cmos, semiconductors, fabrication

This is an excerpt from Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits by Behzad Razavi. What does "field" in field oxide mean here, electric field?

[image]

Comment: I think "field" in this case has a meaning more like "soccer field" than "electric field" since it says it is the area between devices.

Comment: @DKNguyen that is probably right. I as  not an English speaker always wonder what a term really means.

Comment: It sounds weird to me too.

Comment: `field` is an adjective in this usage ... it appears to be similar to farming ... `field soil` on which crops are grown (type of soil) ... `field oxide` on which interconnect lines are deposited

Comment: Maybe whoever named it just liked foxes.

Comment: I suspect the meaning is intended to be the same as the meaning in [vexillology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vexillology). The background area where the "important" part of a design is not present.